# Visual Studio 2010: Folding auto-generated resources behind other files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, msbuild, projects-and-solutions, resx

I have the following file: `Foo.cs` with a `Foo` class inside of it. I can't seem to find the right way to keep my resource files (resx) organized behind their respective files.

1. If I create a Foo.resx the resource file gets folded away nice and tidy behind the Foo.cs class. This, however, causes issues because the standard custom-tool that generates the code attempts to create another `Foo` class (Look at the Foo.Designer.cs: `internal class Foo { ... }`). If my Foo.cs file does not already contain a `Foo` class, this works fine (no naming collision).
2. To fix the naming collision I attempted to give it a custom namespace MyProj.Resources and use an alias to identify it: `using R = MyProj.Resources.Foo;` This still causes issues because the auto-generator has an issue creating a `ResourceManager` properly.
3. If I, instead, name it something along the lines of `FooResx.resx` it does not automatically get folded behind the `Foo.cs` file. Instead, it resides in the solution explorer right below it. Going into the MSBuild (.csproj) file and adding a `<DependentUpon>` tag, then Visual Studio neatly tucks away my FooResx.resx file. However, I can't actually use any of the resources from that file because the auto-generated code has an issue creating a `ResourceManager` properly.

Basically, is there any way to have the Resource files (resx) fold behind a cs file and still work properly using the standard Custom Tool (`ResXFileCodeGenerator`)?

---

I do realize that I can always place all my resources into a file within the properties folder: resources.resx. I'm trying to organize them better than that though.

---

**Update:**

I decided to manually edit the auto-generated code and make it partial. This allowed the code to compile, but I still ran into the same issue (Issue #2). It seems that if a resource file is folded behind (manually or automatically) another code file then the `ResourceManager` has trouble finding the `*.resource` file. This might be an issue I'll have to raise with Microsoft Connect about the `ResXFileCodeGenerator` tool. It needs to be able to locate the proper `*.resource` file when folded behind other files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to make your classes and your generated code **partial classes** - if you look at a .Designer.cs (from a System.Windows.Forms.Form for example) you will discover that it declares something like `partial class Foo`.

**Foo.cs**

```
public partial class Foo
{
}
```

**Foo.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Foo
{
}
```

---

*Edit*

It turns out that `StronglyTypedResourceBuilder` or `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` insists on generating classes with either `internal` or `public` access modifier (it can be set in the .resx).

Setting `ResXFileCodeGenerator` as the *CustomTool* in the properties of your .resx still doesn't give you the behaviour you'd see in a generated .Desinger.cs of a `Form`.

Comment: Actually the designer class (at least for auto-generated resx files) does not generate a partial method.

Comment: @myermian I just compared how this works when adding a resource to how it is laid out with a `Form` which comes with a .Designer.cs. Anyway you sould be fine if your Foo class in Foo.cs is declared as `partial`.

Comment: No, the generator tools **DO NOT** generate partial classes, so I can not make my class partial to combine with it.